# .Net targeting framework 4.5 only sees 4.0 references?

Tags: c#, reference, frameworks, .net-4.5

I have a project in .Net 4.5, however when I try to add a framework reference all that is available to me are 4.0 options. Why is this happening and what can I do to get the 4.5 references options?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I added image and removed `c#-4` tag. actually .Net framework versions are different from C# versions. currently latest c# version is c#6.

Comment: If you see Targeting .Net framework 4.5 in that window there is nothing wrong in your solution.

Comment: Well, I need this class available for a piece of code I wish to write in the solution.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

But it is a 4.5 version class. It is not available in my project, which is also 4.5. What do I need to do to make it available?

Comment: No, you are looking at the 4.5/4.6 MSDN documentation, the Bitmap class goes all the way back to version 1.0.  Simply add a reference to the assembly that contains the class.  Annotated in the header of the article with **Assembly**, it is System.Drawing

Answer (score 0):

That's another direct result of .NET 4.5 in place upgrading .NET 4.0. Th assembly version you saw in VS should not change, while the actual file version if you check in Windows Explorer updated.

This kind of design gives maximum compatibility to applications as they can load the new assemblies just as usual. Assume Microsoft changed the number to 4.5 as you desired, such applications would throw `FileNotFoundException` which can be quite harmful.